# Relation between different rows from 2 tables Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent

I want to make the connection between two tables, categories and subcategories, to display them in the navbar. Parent_id corresponds to the category table id

```
Table Categories

ID  Title
1.  Beds
2.  Mattresses

Table Subcategories

ID Title           Parent_id
1. Superimposed      1
2. Single            1
3. Arches            2
4. Foam              2
```

Subcategory.php model

```
Class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Category.php Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }
}
```

PostsController.php Controller

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $subcategory = Subcategory::with('category')->get();
        return view('posts.index', compact('subcategory'));

    }
}
```

Navbar.blade.php . Is linked with posts.blade.php

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
                  **@foreach($category as $subcat)**
                        <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="200">**{{$subcat->category->category}}**<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="yamm-content">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <h5>Categorii</h5>
                                                <ul>
                                                  <li>
                                                    <a href="category.html">{**{Here i need to display the subcategories}**}</a>
                                                  </li>  
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </ul>
                                            </div><!-- /.yamm-content -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                @endforeach
```

In this moment it displays Beds Beds Mattresses Mattresses.How can I do to display in first place the categories and after the subcategories? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do `$subcategory = Subcategory::with('category')->get();` Why not do `Category::with('subcategory')->get()` so you can loop it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are getting the category name for each subcategory.

You can do the inverse thing in your controller, instead of getting the subcategories with categories, you get the categories with subcategories.

Instead of : `Subcategory::with('category')->get();`

Do : `Category::with('subcategory')->get();`

Then in your view, do a normal foreach :

PostsController.php

```
<?php
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $categories = Category::with('subcategory')->get();
        return view('posts.index', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

Index.blade.php

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="200">
            **{{$category->title (or whatever the name is)}}**<b class="caret"></b>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li>
                 <div class="yamm-content">
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-3">
                             <h5>Categorii</h5>
                                 <ul>
                                     @foreach($category->subcategory as $sub)
                                         <li>
                                             <a href="category.html">
                                                 {{ $sub->title (or whatever the name is)}}
                                             </a>
                                          </li>  
                                      @endforeach
                                 </ul>
                            <!-- Closing tags here -->
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you sire for the help.I've been struggling for  hours to resolve this problem. 10XThx.